# Can't update the Fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin, fragmentpageradapter

**I have written the following code for the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to set up the ViewPager.**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {

    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment = mFragmentList[position]

    override fun getCount(): Int = mFragmentList.size

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = mFragmentTitleList[position]

}
```

And in the Activity, I have the following method to set up the view pager.

```
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, dataList: List<CholesterolMonthlySummary>) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Size of the dataList passing through setupViewPager is ${dataList.size}")

    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(CholesterolPagingFragment.newInstance(ArrayList(dataList), CHOL))
    adapter.addFragment(CholesterolPagingFragment.newInstance(ArrayList(dataList), LDL))
    adapter.addFragment(CholesterolPagingFragment.newInstance(ArrayList(dataList), HDL))
    adapter.addFragment(CholesterolPagingFragment.newInstance(ArrayList(dataList), TRIG))
    viewPager.adapter = adapter

}
```

When new data set comes in I again call the above method and change the adapter again but my views which have already instantiated doesn't get updated. Only the views which were not instantiated gets updated.

I have even tried `notifyDataSetChange()` adding the following code to Adapter but that also doesn't work.

```
override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any?): Int = FragmentPagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
```

Comment: you can have a callback and then update your list in fragment when you receive  new data

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` directly when you want to update view.

And maybe you need to clear `mFragmentList` and `mFragmentTitleList` before insert new data?